# Login com facebook app android

Tags: android, facebook

Estou criando um app que faz login com facebook, ja baixei o sdk do facebook importei no ecplise, criei o meu projeto e agora preciso importar, ate ai tudo bem eu segui esse tutorial

http://www.devmedia.com.br/integrando-aplicacoes-android-com-o-facebook/27567

consegui apontar o sdk do face com meu projeto, mas nao mesclou nada e quando vou importar por exemplo import com.facebook.android.Facebook; ele nao reconhece

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ????????????????